# Program print -1

Tags: java

```
public class Home {

       private static Home home = new Home();
       private static int DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS = 4;
       private final int rooms;

       public Home() {
          rooms = DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS - 1;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(home.rooms);
       }

    }
```

Why does this print -1?

Comment: Is this a puzzle or are you experiencing a problem?

Comment: Well, surely you can tell us what it prints. We could then tell you why. Also, what is the chunk of invalid code at the end of your question about?

Comment: New user, new account, first question is from your homework? are you for reals buddy?

Answer (score 2):

The answer `-1` is right,
If you want answer as `3` then your code should be,

```
 private static int DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS = 4;
 private static Home home = new Home();
```

The reason for the answer `-1` in your first case is that when statement `private static Home home = new Home();` is executed the `DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS` value is not assigned to `4` as the statement is after constructor line. Thus `DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS` is having it's default `int` value which is `0`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the order of your statements.

when you write

```
   private static Home home = new Home();
```

constructor called before the  statement

```
   private static int DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS = 4;
```

So at the time of executing constructor `DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS` value is `0`.

```
 public Home() {
          rooms = DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS - 1; // 0-1
       }
```

To see the change , first assign the value and then call the constructor

```
private static int DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS = 4;
private static Home home = new Home();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling constructor before you assign the value to the static variable.
So in the constructor code, there no value of static variable.

Swap the sequence of the statements as

```
 private static int DEFAULT_NR_OF_ROOMS = 4;
 private static Home home = new Home();
```

Then you will get answer as `3`, as when constructor is called, static variable has been assigned with the value.